# Get the components on scikit-learn PCA without using "internal" API

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

After running `sklearn.decomposition.PCA.fit()` on some data I want to get out the component vectors. There is a member variable `PCA.components_` but AFAIK the underscore at the end means that it is not part of the public API. Is there a public way of getting the components?

I tried using `PCA.inverse_transform(np.eye(n_components))` but it just gave me n_components copies of the first component.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can safely use `PCA.components_`. As you can read in [contributing guide](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/index.html#estimated-attributes)

> Estimated Attributes
>
> Attributes that have been estimated from the data must always have a name **ending** with trailing underscore, for example the coefficients of some regression estimator would be stored in a `coef_` attribute after `fit()` has been called.

Generally speaking only single **leading** underscore is used in Python to mark objects intended for internal use. You can read more in [PEP8 - Naming Conventions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions)